# PHP - Parsing Json correctly

Tags: php, json

I have a json decoded that looks like :

```
[Guadeloupe] => stdClass Object
    (
        [579650] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => Carat
                [postal_code] => 97139
                [lat] => 16,275890246307
                [lng] => -61,511925458908
                [url] => 579650-carat
                [pos_type_has_page] => t
            )
         [579651] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => Carat
                [postal_code] => 97139
                [lat] => 16,275890246307
                [lng] => -61,511925458908
                [url] => 579650-carat
                [pos_type_has_page] => t
            )
        [579655] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => Carat
                [postal_code] => 97139
                [lat] => 16,275890246307
                [lng] => -61,511925458908
                [url] => 579650-carat
                [pos_type_has_page] => t
            )
    )

[Martinique] => stdClass Object
    (
        [154161] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => Grain D'Or 
                [postal_code] => 97232 
                [lat] => 14,619419176343
                [lng] => -61,020416975021
                [url] => 154161-grain-dor-
                [pos_type_has_page] => t
            )

    )

[Guyane française] => stdClass Object
    (
        [154146] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => Bijouterie Buirette
                [postal_code] => 97300
                [lat] => 4,935763
                [lng] => -52,333749
                [url] => 154146-bijouterie-buirette
                [pos_type_has_page] => t
            )

    )
```

actually I don't have any idea how to get values from it correctly, without using many loop foreach($key => $value), I want to get these data :

$country, $name, $lat, $lng and store them in array.

```
$store = array(
     'country'=>$country,
     'name'=>$name,
     'lat'=>$lat,
     'lng '=>$lng ,
)
```

Here is my current code:

```
foreach($content as $store) {
            $store = (array) $store;

            foreach($store as $key => $value) {
                $country = $key;
                $value = (array) $value;
                foreach($value as $key1 => $data) {
                    $title = $data->name;
                    $coordlat = $data->lat;
                    $coordlng = $data->lng;     

                    $store_data = array(
                        'name'=>$title,
                        'latitude'=>$coordlat,
                        'longitude'=>$coordlng,
                        'original_country'=>$country,
                    );
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Your first 2 foreach loops are enough, just use `$value->name` and so one then. Also you don't need to cast your objects to arrays.

Comment: country might have many stores, I edited my first message, so $value->name it will not work I think

Comment: It should still work.

Comment: Just like this: http://pastebin.com/S7UhC1Wh

Answer (score 0):

```
 $allStore = array();    
foreach($content as $storeArray) {

     foreach($storeArray as $key => $value) {
               $country = $key;
               $name = $value->name;
               $latitude = $value->lat;
               $longitude = $value->lng;
               $store = array(
                      'name'=>$name,
                    'latitude'=>$latitude,
                    'longitude'=>$longitude,
                    'country'=>$country
                )



            }

//if you want, you can actually now store each of the data formatted out into another array i.e multidimensional array

       $allStore[] = $store;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try an option 'assoc'=true in json_decode() function. It will convert objects to arrays wich are more convinient to handle in php. Then you can retrieve your data like this:

```
$retrieved_data = json_decode($json_data,true);
$name = $retrieved_data['Martinique']['154161']['name'];
```